# Firestore Security Rule String check every element in an array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore security rules to enforce the type of data the user can save into Firestore. For example, I would like to restrict `field1`, `field2`, `field3` of one document to only string, and restrict the entries to letters only. I have the above codes:

```
   function string_check() {
      let string_keys = ["age_preference", "native_language", "native_location", "displayed_name", "language_level", "learning_language"];
      let string_rule = "[a-zA-Z]*";
      if (request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(string_keys)) {
        return true if the field containing one of string_keys matches string_rule
      }
    }
```

I am trying to build a function that if any fields from `request.resource.data` contains any of the `string_keys`, then I check if that field satisfies the regrex rule. If it does, I allow write, it it does not, then I block write. I am not quite sure how should I implement this. To my understanding, Firestore security rules does not allow looping or foreach.

Comment: You're going to have to expand your code to check each named key in its own expression, and combine all the expressions with a logical AND.

Comment: I am not sure if rules were designed for such purpose. I would say that such check should be implemented on  application level, where you can easily use any loops and collection features that will make the problem almost trivial. Just my personal opinion of course...